# Create an order with different quantities of products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have page that list the products available and I want the user to be able to indicate which quantity of each product he wants. I'm not sure what is the correct way to create the form. I have done this but I'm sure it's not the best way to do it...

```rb
<%= form_tag create_order_path, :method => :post do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <input name="ads[<%= product.id %>][quantity]">
  <% end %>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Pay"></input>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have

```rb
@products = []
params[:ads].each do |ad|
   if product[1][:quantity].to_i > 0
     @products << [product[0], product[1][:quantity]]
   end
end
```

My goal is to have a list of products ids and the quantities needed so that I can create an order with it. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the HTML form this creates? Are you asking if the form could be better or if there is a better way to store the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders, join_table: PurchaseProduct.table_name

  has_many :purchase_products
end
```

Order Model

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, join_table: PurchaseProduct.table_name

  has_many :purchase_products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_products
end
```

PurchaseProduct Model

```
class PurchaseProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
  validates :quantity, length: { minimum: 1 }
end
```

Order Form

```
  ...
  <%= form.fields_for :purchase_products do |another_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= another_form.label :product %>
            <%= another_form.select(:product_id, Product.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, ) %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= another_form.label :quantity %>
            <%= another_form.number_field :quantity %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ...
```

For render **x** times product and quantity `x.times { @order.purchase_products.build }`

See full steps to build this [here](https://github.com/thiaguerd/rails_complex_forms_with_nested_attributes)